# How to make the checkbox visible in wix installer?

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I have an issue in WIX installer. At the end of the finish dialog, there is a check-box. By default it is enabled to run an application. I don't know why the check-box is hiding whenever the finish dialog comes. Please help me on this?

I need to make the check-box visible by default at the finish dialog?

Answer (score 1):

WiX will only show that checkbox if the `WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOXTEXT` property is set. Include the following somewhere under your `Product` element:

```
<Property 
   Id="WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOXTEXT" 
   Value="Launch Application" />
```

For more details, see the section [How To: Run the Installed Application After Setup](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/ui_and_localization/run_program_after_install.html) in the WiX Toolset manual.

Comment: the same code am using in another dialog, checkbox is visible clearly. but in finish dialog, it is showing error.